# Analogue of background thread in VSIX project?

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Basically, I'm trying to carry out a number of tasks *while a Visual Studio instance is running.*

I have not been able to find anything yet in the Visual Studio SDK reference which is analogous to a background thread or IsRunning or anything like that. All I can do so far is respond to very specific events such as the view changing or the cursor being moved.

I don't even understand what event fires when the Visual Studio instance finishes loading.

Surely there must be something pretty big that I'm missing here? What manages the lifecycle of a Visual Studio instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So nothing prevents you from launching a background thread and doing work there. All sorts of components do that all the time. There are some ways you can [register your package to load in various scenarios](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2013/MZ2013027.aspx), and from there you could always launch a thread.

Be careful of course with any of these -- if everybody did "I'll run a background thread once VS loads", your CPU cores would be very, very busy! There's an older concept in VS called the "idle loop" where some code can be registered to run whenever the UI thread doesn't have a message to pump, and the internal joke is that the idle loop is never idle.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you!